# jQuery Date picker allows to copy paste words like 'hello' 'adad' ? How to restrict it?

Tags: jquery, jsp, spring-mvc

Here is my jQuery code

```
 $( "#loanMaturityDate" ).datepicker({
          dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
          changeMonth:true,
          changeYear:true,
        });
```

I have observed that it allows me to paste letters in the input box even if i have made it readonly

```
<form:input  id = "loanMaturityDate" path = "loanMaturityDate" readonly = "readonly" size = "16"/>
```

Also allows me to enter numbers like 1111111 using keyboard.

What is the reason for it ? How can i restrict that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can set the date picker input text as read only using the following.
>     when you click on the calendar then date picker will show i shareing you the code.

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Icon trigger</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"href=
 "http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script>
$(function() {

$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
  showOn: "button",
  buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
  buttonImageOnly: true
});


$("#datepicker").attr('readonly', true);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" readonly="readonly"/></p>


</body>
</html>
```